# About avoiding IFs in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

Somebody knows how to avoid using these IF statements?

```
float v = 9999.0;
if (a.x > 0.0 && a.x < v) { v = a.x; }
if (a.y > 0.0 && a.y < v) { v = a.y; }
if (a.z > 0.0 && a.z < v) { v = a.z; }
```

Initially I used the following lines but then I realized I only wanted the minimum iff it does not equal zero.

```
float v = min(a.x, min(a.y, a.z));
```

I also assume that a.xyz are always greater or equal than zero, being at least one of the components greater than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a construct like

```
vec3 b=a+10000.0*step(0.0, -a);
float v=min(b.x, min(b.y, b.z));
```

which also assumes (as your code does) that your minimal element is < 10000. Note that the `step(0,0, -a)` was chosen in favour of `(1.0-step(0.0, a))` since step is defined to return 0.0 only if the value is below the edge (0.0 in this case), not if it is equal. In pratice it might still be a good idea to use a small epsilon value.